# substract or add time on timestamps of pcap file

Tags: time, lua, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I'm seeking for a way how to manipulate timestamps of PCAP files.
For example, substract amount of times from packets or add.
Is it possilbe to do so on wireshark or tshark? Or do I need to write some lua code to do so?

Please let me know if you've known a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust timestamps with [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html).  For example, to adjust the timestamp of all packets 1 hour later:

```
editcap -t 3600 file.pcap file_plus1hour.pcap
```

You can also adjust the timestamps in Wireshark using *"Edit -> Time Shift..."*; however, it's currently not possible to save the time-shifted file from Wireshark.